# Image upload on CKEditor & ASP.NET 4, response to upload iframe error

Tags: c#, javascript, ckeditor, htmlspecialchars

I am using the CKEditor wysiwyg editor with the upload image option.  I've setup the JS by setting the 'filebrowserUploadUrl' settings attribute.  I wrote some code to handle the upload and this all works fine.  The problem comes when I try to send the response back to the CKEditor upload iframe.  I am just trying to send a JS script tag back with this line of JS:

```
window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( " + CKEditorFuncNum + ", '" + relativePath + "' );
```

What this should do is populate the URL field and show a preview of the image on the Image Info tab of the Image popup.  This doesn't work and if I view the source of the iframe on the Upload tab, the JS script tag is encoded, it looks like this:

```
&lt;script type='text/javascript'&gt; window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction( 2, '/uploads/ducati-916-2.jpg' ); &lt;/script&gt;
```

I am using the:

```
Response.Write(...)
```

and also I tried

```
Response.BinaryWrite(...)
```

to write out the js tag string.

I didn't think this was the normal behavior of Response.Write() but maybe its getting encoded elsewhere.

Any clue why this string is getting encoded?  Any help here is appreciated.

Thanks.
Ian

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to simply make **CKEditorFuncNum** and **relativePath** protected member variables and write it like this on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(
            <%= CKEditorFuncNum %>, '<%= relativePath  %>');
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better to have the html in some type of view, then pass the 2 parameters to the view from a controller like the above answer describes.  In my case, since I was building a JSON api and there were no views, the view model was just getting json encoded and sent as output, I had to set the Response.ContentType = "application/json";